# Joda time plusDays getting wrong date

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am using this code:

```
 DateTime(date)//Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020
                .plusDays(days) // 103
                .toDate()
```

And the result is `Fri Dec 18 23:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020` instead of `Dec 19`.
With some dates it work well, with other the result date-1, I guess the problem is with number of days in month, but does `plusDays()` not consider it?

Comment: Do you have to use JodaTime or can you use `java-time` (Java 8+)?

Comment: If `java-time` supported by Android api 21+ so I can use

Comment: This is likely due to *daylight saving time*. The timezone offset changed from +3 to +2 somewhere near 25 October.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With some dates it work well, with other the result date-1, I guess
> the problem is with number of days in month, but does plusDays() not
> consider it?

It does consider it. The problem with the two date-time strings you have mentioned is that they belong to different Zone-Offset (the first one is with UTC+3 and the second one with UTC+2). Given below is how to do it with the same Zone-Offset.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy");
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020", formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
        // With Zone-Offset of UTC+2
        System.out.println(dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(2)));

        // Add 103 days
        DateTime dateTimeAfter103Days = dateTime.plusDays(103);
        System.out.println(dateTimeAfter103Days);
        System.out.println(dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(2)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-05T21:00:00.000Z
2020-08-05T23:00:00.000+02:00
2020-11-16T21:00:00.000Z
2020-08-05T23:00:00.000+02:00
```

I recommend you use the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. If your Android API level is still not compliant with Java8, check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) and [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

The following table shows an [overview of modern date-time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html):
[image]

**With modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define formatter for your date-time string
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O u");

        // Parse the given date0-time string into OffsetDateTime object
        OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020", formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);

        // Add 103 days to the OffsetDateTime object
        OffsetDateTime dateTimeAfter103Days = dateTime.plusDays(103);
        System.out.println(dateTimeAfter103Days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-06T00:00+03:00
2020-11-17T00:00+03:00
```

**Alternatively,**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define formatter for your date-time string
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

        // If you do not need Zone Id or Zone Offset information, you can go for
        // LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020", formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);

        // You can convert LocalDateTime object into an OffsetDateTime by applying the
        // Zone-Offset e.g. the following line applies UTC+03:00 hours to LocalDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = dateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(3));
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Add 103 days to the LocalDateTime object
        LocalDateTime dateTimeAfter103Days = dateTime.plusDays(103);
        System.out.println(dateTimeAfter103Days);

        odt = dateTimeAfter103Days.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(3));
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-06T00:00
2020-08-06T00:00+03:00
2020-11-17T00:00
2020-11-17T00:00+03:00
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `java.time` and it is supported in lower Android APIs, because there's [API desugaring in Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) now.

There's a zone-aware class (`java.time.ZonedDateTime`) and an offset-aware one (`java.time.OffsetDateTime`), but your example `String` just contains an offset from GMT / UTC. That's why I would use an `OffsetDateTime` that parses the exact moment in time and then adds a day.

Here's a simple example that defines a formatter which parses the given `String` and uses it for the output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String
    String date = "Fri Dec 18 23:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020";
    // create a formatter that is able to parse and output the String
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu",
                                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
    // parse the String using the formatter defined above
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, dtf);
    System.out.println("OffsetDateTime parsed is\t" + odt.format(dtf));
    
    // add a day to the date part
    OffsetDateTime dayLater = odt.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Adding a day results in\t\t" + dayLater.format(dtf));
}
```

This outputs

```
OffsetDateTime parsed is    Fri Dec 18 23:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020
Adding a day results in     Sat Dec 19 23:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020
```

If you are interested in outputting dates only (no time part or offset), there's another handy thing in those classes, that is easy extraction of date- or time-part. You can do the following with an `OffsetDateTime`, for example:

```
// extract the part that only holds information about day of month, month of year and year
LocalDate dateOnly = odt.toLocalDate();
// print the default format (ISO standard)
System.out.println(dateOnly);
// or define and use a totally custom format
System.out.println(dateOnly.format(
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, 'the' dd. 'of' MMMM uuuu",
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH)
                    )
);
```

That would output

```
2020-12-18
Friday, the 18. of December 2020
```

In case you are dealing with a `DatePicker datePicker`, you can receive selected values by `getYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDayOfMonth()`, then create a

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(datePicker.getYear(),
                                   datePicker.getMonth(), 
                                   datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
```

and then simply add a day by `localDate.plusDays(1);`

Comment: `but your example String just contains an offset from GMT / UTC` it actually java Date object from DatePicker

Comment: @PavelPoley You can get the year, month and day of month from a `DatePicker` and just create a `LocalDate` from it. I wouldn't use `java.util.Date` anymore because of problems like the one in your example. See my edited answer...

Comment: Why to use `localDate.plusDays(1)`?

Comment: @PavelPoley that's just an example, you can input any `int` there. If you have `int days = 103;`, then do `localDate.plusDays(days);`, no problem.