# Joda Time toDate() wrong result

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am using this code:

`date` - Date object from `DatePicker`, as string `Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020`

```
mDate = DateTime(date)
           .withHourOfDay(0)
           .withMinuteOfHour(0)
           .withSecondOfMinute(0)
           .withMillisOfSecond(0)
           .toDate()
```

The result
`mDate` - `Wed Sep 09 03:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020`

What wrong with this?

Comment: why it is correct? util.date without time zone and joda time with time zone?

Comment: Pavel Poley - Your conversion is wrong which I've already explained in my answer. Unless you tell me what exactly you are not able to understand, how can I help you further? Because of your wrong conversion, `mDate` represents a different date-time from the one which is there in your `DatePicker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not converting the `DateTime` object to `java.util.Date` correctly. A correct way is to get the milliseconds from `DateTime` object and initialize the `java.util.Date` with the milliseconds.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy");

        // Date-time string from DatePicker
        String strDateTime = "Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020";

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);

        // No. of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 
        long millis = dateTime.getMillis();
        System.out.println(millis);

        Date mDate = new Date(millis);
        // Display java.util.Date object in my default time-zone (BST)
        System.out.println(mDate);

        //Display java.util.Date in a different time-zone and using custom format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(mDate));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-09T21:00:00.000Z
1599685200000
Wed Sep 09 22:00:00 BST 2020
Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020
```

**Note:** `java.util.Date` does not represent a Date/Time object. It simply represents the no. of milliseconds from the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. It does not have any time-zone or zone-offset information. When you print it, Java prints the string obtained by applying the time-zone of your JVM. If you want to print it in some other timezone, you can do so using the `SimpleDateFormat` as shown above.

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. If your Android API level is still not compliant with Java8, check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) and [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

The following table shows an [overview of modern date-time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html):
[image]

Comment: The new Java api contains `time-zone or zone-offset information`?

Comment: @PavelPoley - Yes, I had shown it in my last [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774901/10819573). I've provided you with relevant links which you should explore. Feel free to let me know if you want me to post some more code.

Comment: While I wholeheartedly approve of switching to `java.time` it's unfortunately only been included in Android since API Level 26 (Android O, 8.0) and many people are still targeting lower levels like that and thus can't use it on Android. Something like joda-time or threetenbp is their best bet.

Comment: If I where using `java.util.date` inside POJO's, which class in the new api is the alternative?

Comment: @PavelPoley - It depends on what you need e.g. if you need just year, month and day, you should go with `LocalDate`. If you need to have year, month, day, and time, you should go with `LocalDateTime`. If you need date, time and time-zone/zone-offset information, you should go with `ZonedDateTime`/`OffsetDateTime`. The table which I have posted in my answer gives you an overview and you can choose the class as per your need,.

Comment: Basically I need `year`,`month`,`day`, but I also need support for `day difference` and `plus days`(this function need time/offset?), also this date object should be stored in Firestore document

Comment: @JoachimSauer Joda-Time isn’t included in Android either. We need to add an external dependency anyway. So we may just as well pick the backport of java.time, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: @PavelPoley For year, month and day, day difference and plus days use either `LocalDate` from Joda-Time or `LocalDate` from java.time.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash I migrated to Java time api, to do all the calculations (DAYS.between and plusDays()), work fine now, but with support to old util.date, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @PavelPoley - You are most welcome. Wish you success!